# Show there exists a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, spheres

> Show that there exists a quotient map $S^2 \to S^1 \times S^1$. Do not write an explicit formula.

I don't see how I can turn a sphere into a torus since a torus has a hole in it. I also don't think I can turn the sphere into a closed cylinder first (to connect the two ends of the disks) because the cylinder has "edges" and it wouldn't be continuous to "sharpen" parts of the sphere into these "edges".

Comment: The torus is a quotient of the square $[0,1]^2$. A closed hemisphere is homeomorphic to the square.

Comment: Note that you only need to find a continuous surjection. It will automatically be a quotient map.